# Possible values for $L_x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space

I've a physical system with $l=1$ and I have to calculate the values I can obtain if I measure $L_x$ and their probability.

I know that:

- the values I can obtain are $\ m=0, \pm 1$
- $\displaystyle L_x=\frac{L_+ + L_-}{2}$
- $L_x|1, m>_x=\hbar m |1, m>_x$

But I can't understand, for example, why I should obtain 
$|1, 1>_x=\frac{1}{2}[|1,1>+\sqrt{2}|1,0>+|1,-1>] $

(I have obtained $|1, 1>_x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} |1,0>$)

Can I have some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to exploit the symmetries here. So, instead of mindlessly going through the algebra, solving equations etc. you just use the fact that you are free to call any direction the x-direction, and set up a right handed coordinate system. In particular, this means that you are free to cyclically permute x, y, z in the equations. The problem of expressing $|1,1\rangle_x$ in terms of the eigenvectors of $L_z$, can be solved as follows. If you apply the raising operator for the x-component of the angular momentum, $L_x^{+}$ to $|1,1\rangle_x$ then this should yield zero. But to do this we need to express $L_x^{+}$ in terms of $L_z$ and $L_z^{\pm}$. You can do that as follows. We have:

$$L_z^{+} = L_x + i L_y$$

If you cyclically permute x,y, and z, you get:

$${L_{x}}^{+} = L_y + i L_z$$

We can write this as:

$$L_x^{+} =\frac{1}{2 i}\left({L_{z}}^{+} - {L_{z}}^{-}\right) + i L_z$$

This means that the state $|1,1\rangle_x$ satisfies the equation

$$\left[L_z^{+} - {L_z}^{-} - 2 L_z\right]|1,1\rangle_x = 0$$

If we take inner product with $|1,1\rangle$, we get the equation:

$$\sqrt{2}\langle 1,0|1,1\rangle_x - 2 \langle 1,1|1,1\rangle_x = 0$$

Taking the inner product with $|1,0\rangle$ gives:

$$\langle 1,-1|1,1\rangle_x = \langle 1,1|1,1\rangle_x$$

So, we see that the $|1,0\rangle$ component of the state is $\sqrt{2}$ times that of the other two components, and by normalizing the state you obtain the overall factor of 1/2 in your equation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't understood how you have obtained $$\sqrt{2}\langle 1,0|1,1\rangle_x - 2 \langle 1,1|1,1\rangle_x = 0$$ and $$\langle 1,-1|1,1\rangle_x = \langle 1,1|1,1\rangle_x$$.. Could you explain me a little more? A lot of thanks for your answer!

Comment: In $\langle 1,0|L_z^{+} - {L_z}^{-} - 2 L_z|1,1\rangle_x = 0$ You apply the operators to the bra vectors. You then use that the way an operator acts on a bra vector is the same the Hermitian conjugate would act on the corresponding ket vector. So, e.g. the raising operator will act on a bra vector in the same way as the lowering operator would on the corresponding ket vector.